# How can I use the prepend() function?

Tags: jquery

I have this code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>append demo</title>
        <style>
            p {
            background: yellow;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="hhh">I would like to say: </p>

        <script>
            var x = document.getElementById("hhh");
            x.prepend("Hello");
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

How can I use the `x` variable to put anything I want in it with the `prepend()` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `x` variable holds a DOMElement, so to use jQuery methods on it you need to put it in to a jQuery object. Try this:

```
var x = document.getElementById("hhh");
$(x).prepend("Hello");
```

You can also use jQuery to select the element and turn this in to a one-liner:

```
$("#hhh").prepend("Hello");
```

Finally, `prepend()` will put the specified string as the first child of the element, in your case resulting in `HelloI would like to say:`. From the look of your code you may wish to use `append()` instead to put the string at the end of the specified element.

Comment: I try it but it give me this error in consol (Uncaught TypeError: $(...).prepend is not a function) i know that your code is right i try it in jsfiddle but why it give me that error in chrom browser

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to achieve this is:

```
$('#hhh').append('Hello');
```

If you're receiving an error then most likely your link to the jQuery library is broken.

Comment: give me : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prepend' of null

Comment: That line of JS cannot give you an error. Are you sure you're linking to the appropriate jquery library and there are no conflicts?